# Change the "No matching records found" message in Gridjs gridjs-react

Tags: gridjs, gridjs-react

I am using `gridjs-react` library and cannot customize the "No matching records found" message.

[image: No matching records found]

I have been able to customize many parts of gridjs like this:

```
 style={{
          td: {
            height: '40px',
            maxWidth: '60px',
            fontSize: '12px',
            padding: '1px',
          },
          th: {
            fontSize: '12px',
          },
          footer: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            padding: '12px',
            backgroundColor: '#f9fafb',
          },
        }}
        language={{
          pagination: {
            previous: '前',
            next: '次',
            showing: '\n',
            to: '~',
            of: '件目を表示（全',
            results: '件）',
          },
        }}
```

But when it come to the `No matching records found` when no records, I have been struggling very hard.

In the [documentation](https://gridjs.io/docs/config/className/) there is a `notfound` classname, but no try has worked until now.

For example, adding

```
      <Grid
        data={rows}
        columns={cols}
        notfound="my new message" 
      />

     // or

      <Grid
        data={rows}
        columns={cols}
        style={{
        ...
        notfound:"my new message" 
        ...
        }}
        
/>
```

in the props or `notfound:"my new message"` in the style of the grid. There is also a [language docs](https://gridjs.io/docs/config/language) to configure many details, results had been the same.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way, the answer is:

```
language={{
        pagination: {
          previous: '前',
          next: '次',
          showing: '\n',
          to: '~',
          of: '件目を表示（全',
          results: '件）',
        },
        noRecordsFound: '該当する情報が見つかりません',
      }}
```

Found it [here](https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs/blob/master/src/i18n/en_US.ts).